# IDA Pro how to associate a address to a symbol

Tags: python, ida

I make a double word data in .data section, and the data is an address which points to a string, the string has a name created by IDA itself, I want to convert the data to strings name, like this:

[image]

so, how can I do this in python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idc.op_plain_offset(ea, n, base) could do this.
but the version of the IDA i use is 7.5, if you use IDA 6.x, function name may be different!